# Update the display when :normal is busy

Tags: normal-mode, macro, redraw

The [n]vim manual on :normal says "The display is not updated while ":normal" is busy". Is there a way to have it do so? If not, is there a plugin that defines its own version of :normal, or some change I could make in the source code and rebuild?

For context, I'm doing some very complex tasks with macros (i.e. things that should not be done with macros), and I want to watch them execute. Some macro @g moves throughout the text and invokes an @i macro in various places, which is recursive and dies when it's input is invalid. I use :normal so that once @i runs out of input and dies, it won't kill @g, but it also makes @i execute in one step which is undesirable.